# How can I fix the default search engine in Chromium on Linux Mint 11?

Tags: linux-mint, chromium, google-search

Lame. Linux Mint comes with some pretty nasty defaults as far as setting the default search engine go. How can I set it to Google proper? Can someone copy and paste the URL to use which is working for them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what I was able to recover from another computer:

```
{google:baseURL}search?{google:RLZ}{google:acceptedSuggestion}{google:originalQueryForSuggestion}sourceid=chrome&ie={inputEncoding}&q=%s
```

Thank goodness I had this other computer lying around, this was literally driving me insane.

Answer (score 1):

I've had [this](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/139) page bookmarked for a while.

Go to Google.com--In the search box, right click.  In the resulting menu, select "Create Search."

In the resulting pop up box called Search Engine, copy everything in the 'address' field (you may have to click on 'Details' in order to see it).  It will be a URL with a very long string of characters in it.

For the 10.5 Opera and up, click on Menu, Settings, Preferences, Search Tab--Highlight Google and click Edit.  Again the search engine box pops up..Click details to get to the address field and paste the URL from step 2 into the address field.  Then click okay.  (For older versions, click on Tools, Preference, Search Tab, Edit.

Comment: No dice, when I right click the search input on Google.com from Chromium, I don't get any options to "Create Search".

Comment: All I have is "Edit Search Engines."

Comment: Is there a generic URL you could send me off of your browser?