# How do I change linux mint's default search in Chromium to normal?

Tags: linux-mint, chromium, search-engines

I've used Linux Mint for over 6 months, and have been loving it until I installed Mint 11 today. Everything was great until I loaded up Chromium and saw that it only allows you to search through Mint's custom Google search, which is unsatisfactory. How do I change the settings so that it's back to normal? Someone asked the same question [earlier](https://superuser.com/questions/289666/how-can-i-fix-the-default-search-engine-in-chromium-on-linux-mint-11), and he ended up sort of answering the question himself, but I don't understand what to do with the info he provides.

Answer (score 11):

What he meant was to right-click on the address bar, and select Edit Search Engines. After entering the Search Engines preferences, change the URL (2nd box) to google.com and replace the text in the 3rd box with:

```
{google:baseURL}search?{google:RLZ}{google:acceptedSuggestion}{google:originalQueryForSuggestion}sourceid=chrome&ie={inputEncoding}&q=%s
```

After entering the information into the boxes, you should be able to search normally again.

Comment: @Ant Davis If this solved your problem, mark this answer as correct. It will help future users who visit this site.

Answer (score 1):

On chromium 88, paste `chrome://settings/searchEngines` in address bar and press enter. Then click on `Add` button and enter the following:

```
Search engine : Google
Keyword : google
URL with %s in place of query : https://www.google.com/search?q=%s
```

Then click on `save` button. Finally, click on the option button at right of the newly added search engine and click on `Make default`.